# Begin Viewing Query Results Before Query Ends

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, informix

Lets say I query a table with 500K rows. I would like to begin viewing any rows in the fetch buffer, which holds the result set, even though the query has not yet completed. I would like to scroll thru the fetch buffer. If I scroll too far ahead, I want to display a message like: "REACHED LAST ROW IN FETCH BUFFER.. QUERY HAS NOT YET COMPLETED".

- Could this be accomplished using fgets() to read the fetch buffer while the query continues building the result set? Doing this implies multi-threading*

Can a feature like this, other than the FIRST ROWS hint directive, be provided in Oracle, Informix, MySQL, or other RDBMS?

The whole idea is to have the ability to start viewing rows before a long query completes, while displaying a counter of how many rows are available for immediate viewing.

EDIT: What I'm suggesting may require a fundamental change in a DB server's architecture, as to the way they handle their internal fetch buffers, e.g. locking up the result set until the query has completed, etc. A feature like the one I am suggesting would be very useful, especially for queries which take a long time to complete. Why have to wait until the whole query completes, when you could start viewing some of the results while the query continues to gather more results!

Comment: @Frank: what platform? How are you accessing the database now? You're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: @Broam, I guess it depends on why you're here answering questions.

Comment: And, +1, cuz it's an interesting question.

Comment: The compensation of helping others is sufficient for me. And I end up being rewarded with plenty of reputation, even though I limit myself to one of the least popular subjects on SO (i.e., MS-ACCESS). I don't understand any motivation beyond my own amusement, so maybe that's why I don't get it.

Comment: Well, there obviously is a way to do this. Most DB clients eg. Toad and SQL Developer use this technique when you execute a query and see the data in a table grid view. the current view fetches only short number of rows and every scroll retrieves rows from the buffer. I would be interested to see a realistic solution to the question asked.

Comment: @Annjawn: Are you sure that Toad & SQL Dev's grid view is not just implementing the FIRST ROWS hint directive?.. Several DB Servers provide this option, however the overall performance of the query suffers, especially when a full table scan or sorting has to take place!.. What I'm talking about is to have the ability to peek at the "Fetch Buffer" which is like an internal temporary table which the server creates to accumulate the queries result set. Most DB servers dont allow this buffer to be accessed, plus a lock is placed on it until the query completes!

Comment: I know that you can set the "Fetch buffer" size, but I am not too sure how you would access it. Even if it were possible, I would be DB specific. I am not aware of a way to do it in Oracle, though I cannot speak about any other Databases. Also, in terms of Oracle, `Full table scans of large tables usually result in physical disk reads and a lower buffer cache hit ratio` so it would not be much of an adventure trying to access the fetch buffer anyways.

Comment: I would think somehow it could be done, or the software engineers could modify the engine to provide access to where the result set is being accumulated, even though the query has not finished its search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three basic limiting factors:

1. The execution plan of the query. If the execution plan has a blocking operation at the end (such as a sort or an eager spool), the engine cannot return rows early in the query execution. It must wait until all rows are fully processed, after which it will return the data as fast as possible to the client. The time for this may itself be appreciable, so this part could be applicable to what you're talking about. In general, though, you cannot guarantee that a query will have much available very soon.
2. The database connection library. When returning recordsets from a database, the driver can use server-side paging or client-side paging. Which is used can and does affect which rows will be returned and when. Client-side paging forces the entire query to be returned at once, reducing the opportunity for displaying any data before it is all in. Careful use of the proper paging method is crucial to any chance to display data early in a query's lifetime.
3. The client program's use of synchronous or asynchronous methods. If you simply copy and paste some web example code for executing a query, you will be a bit less likely to be working with early results while the query is still running—instead the method will block and you will get nothing until it is all in. Of course, server-side paging (see point #2) can alleviate this, however in any case your application will be blocked for at least a short time if you do not specifically use an asynchronous method. For anyone reading this who is using .Net, you may want to check out [Asynchronous Operations in .Net Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zw97wx20%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you get all of these right, and use the FAST FIRSTROW technique, you *may* be able to do some of what you're looking for. But there is no guarantee.

Comment: +1 because you're addressing the inner workings of how engines process queries. So what method does hint directive `FIRST ROWS` (in Informix, I dunno the equivalent for Oracle) use in order to return results quicker than doing a standard query with no hinting?.. Perhaps the design of how queries are processed could be modified to somehow accommodate my idea? I think it could accurately provide users an efficient way for killing time by viewing results while the query keeps chugging away!

Comment: Is it possible for the client to have more than one thread running on the same query request?.. i.e. one thread that submitted the query to the engine, while the other thread is doing a lookahead into the fetch buffer to see if anything has already been deposited in it, while there's IPC going on with the first thread to see if the query has not finished, etc.?

Comment: It sounds like you have a specific DBMS in mind, and one I'm not familiar with. I'm sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: Not really, I'm just thinking that it would be advantageous for any SQL-based server to provide this capability, if its possible to implement. It seems like all SQL-based servers have the same architecture of waiting for a query to complete before the client can access the result set. I can understand if the results which satisfy the criteria need to be sorted before releasing it to the client, but what if there's no sorting (e.g. table scan) and its a huge table?

Comment: I don't think it's any more possible to implement than I stated. If the execution plan has a SORT at the end, how will the engine provide any rows to the client before all rows are discovered? What if the best choice for a final join in a big series of joins is a HASH MATCH, preventing any rows from leaving the engine because it can't probe the left input's hash until that hash is fully built? The engine may still not know which rows will be in the final result or not, so it can't give you any. I truly already gave you the limitations inherent in the system.

Comment: If "the result set is being accumulated" and it IS the final one, then parts 2 and 3 of my answer come into play and those rows *can* be accessed.

Comment: Any improvement in early access to even a partial result set would be welcomed!.. I see that in #3, you make reference to async ops in .NET, so I'm assuming your talking about MS-SQL?.. .NET async ops basically places the query in a background thread to allow the front-end to continue in another thread while the query completes, but that still doesn't allow the front to peek at a partial result set of the query it submitted.

Comment: First of all, using .Net does not imply MS-SQL. It can connect to many database engines. Second, you can too get the partial result set of a submitted query using asynchronous reading! If the execution plan does NOT have a blocking operator (let's say it's doing a loop join, merge join, or lazy spool) it returns rows to the client *before it has found them all*. You can display these found rows as you receive them, before the engine is done with its operation.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with NET. As I read the async link you posted in your answer, I didn't get the impression that the client could begin displaying part of the result-set before a non-blocking query completes. This is good news, as I'm contemplating converting my Informix-SQL app to Access'10/MS-SQL!.. So does the FAST FIRSTROW directive accomplish this?.. If so, is the directive ignored if the optimizer detects a blocking op?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how FASTFIRSTROW works. Note that it is [deprecated in SQL 2005](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/Posts/14808/0163-sql-server-2012-deprecated-features-table-hint-fastfirstrow-msg-321.aspx) and has been replaced with `OPTION (FAST x)`. I have developed ADPs in Access (with a SQL Server back-end) that successfully showed partial result sets before the query had completed. But you have to use an asynchronous method.

Comment: Thank you for choosing my answer!

Comment: Your welcome!.. I read about the (FAST x) hint in [beyondrelational.com](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/77/Posts/14808/0163-sql-server-2012-deprecated-features-table-hint-fastfirstrow-msg-321.aspx) and it addresses, even better, the feature I was looking for in my question. FAST x allows you to specify how many rows you want delivered up front before the query completes. Informix-SQL uses FIRST ROWS hint, however that causes the entire query to take longer to complete.

Answer (score 6):

Paraphrasing:

> I have a table with 500K rows. An ad-hoc query without a good index to support it  requires a full table scan. I would like to immediately view the first rows returned while the full table scan continues. Then I want to scroll through the next results.

It seems that what you would like is some sort of system where there can be two (or more) threads at work.  One thread would be busy synchronously fetching the data from the database, and reporting its progress to the rest of the program.  The other thread would be dealing with the display.

> In the meantime, I would like to display the progress of the table scan, example: "Searching...found 23 of 500,000 rows so far".

It isn't clear that your query will return 500,000 rows (indeed, let us hope it does not), though it may have to scan all 500,000 rows (and may well have only found 23 rows that match so far).  Determining the number of rows to be returned is hard; determining the number of rows to be scanned is easier; determining the number of rows already scanned is very difficult.

> If I scroll too far ahead, I want to display a message like: "Reached last row in look-ahead buffer...query has not completed yet".

So, the user has scrolled past the 23rd row, but the query is not yet completed.

> Can this be done? Maybe like: spawn/exec, declare scroll cursor, open, fetch, etc.?

There are a couple of issues here.  The DBMS (true of most databases, and certainly of IDS) remains tied up as far as the current connection on processing the one statement.  Obtaining feedback on how a query has progressed is difficult.  You could look at the estimated rows returned when the query was started (information in the SQLCA structure), but those values are apt to be wrong.  You'd have to decide what to do when you reach row 200 of 23, or you only get to row 23 of 5,697.  It is better than nothing, but it is not reliable.  Determining how far a query has progressed is very difficult.  And some queries require an actual sort operation, which means that it is very hard to predict how long it will take because no data is available until the sort is done (and once the sort is done, there is only the time taken to communicate between the DBMS and the application to hold up the delivery of the data).

Informix 4GL has many virtues, but thread support is not one of them.  The language was not designed with thread safety in mind, and there is no easy way to retrofit it into the product.

I do think that what you are seeking would be most easily supported by two threads.  In a single-threaded program like an I4GL program, there isn't an easy way to go off and fetch rows while waiting for the user to type some more input (such as 'scroll down the next page full of data').

The FIRST ROWS optimization is a hint to the DBMS; it may or may not give a significant benefit to the perceived performance.  Overall, it typically means that the query is processed less optimally from the DBMS perspective, but getting results to the user quickly can be more important than the workload on the DBMS.

---

Somewhere down below in a much down-voted answer, Frank shouted (but please don't SHOUT):

> That's exactly what I want to do, spawn a new process to begin displaying first_rows and scroll through them even though the query has not completed.

OK.  The difficulty here is organizing the IPC between the two client-side processes.  If both are connected to the DBMS, they have separate connections, and therefore the temporary tables and cursors of one session are not available to the other.

> When a query is executed, a temporary table is created to hold the query results for the current list. Does the IDS engine place an exclusive lock on this temp table until the query completes?

Not all queries result in a temporary table, though the result set for a scroll cursor usually does have something approximately equivalent to a temporary table.  IDS does not need to place a lock on the temporary table backing a scroll cursor because only IDS can access the table.  If it was a regular temp table, there'd still not be a need to lock it because it cannot be accessed except by the session that created it.

> What I meant with the 500k rows, is nrows in the queried table, not how many expected results will be returned.

Maybe a more accurate status message would be:

```
Searching 500,000 rows...found 23 matching rows so far
```

> I understand that an accurate count of nrows can be obtained in sysmaster:sysactptnhdr.nrows?

Probably; you can also get a fast and accurate count with 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TheTable'; this does not scan anything but simply accesses the control data - probably effectively the same data as in the nrows column of the SMI table sysmaster:sysactptnhdr.

So, spawning a new process is not clearly a recipe for success; you have to transfer the query results from the spawned process to the original process.  As I stated, a multithreaded solution with separate display and database access threads would work after a fashion, but there are issues with doing this using I4GL because it is not thread-aware.  You'd still have to decide how the client-side code is going store the information for display.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done, with an analytic function, but Oracle has to full scan the table to determine the count no matter what you do if there's no index. An analytic could simplify your query:

```
SELECT x,y,z, count(*) over () the_count
  FROM your_table
 WHERE ...
```

Each row returned will have the total count of rows returned by the query in the_count. As I said, however, Oracle will have to finish the query to determine the count before anything is returned.

Depending on how you're processing the query (e.g., a PL/SQL block in a form), you could use the above query to open a cursor, then loop through the cursor and display sets of records and give the user the chance to cancel.

Comment: Would changing optimizer goal to `FIRST_ROWS` help ?

Comment: Not if you want the count as well, because oracle, well, has to count all the rows ;-)

Comment: I'm just wondering if there's any way of accessing the temporary file, created by the query, which starts putting results into the result set. If the server can do this, why can't we also have access to it even though the query has not yet completed?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you would accomplish this, since the query has to complete prior to the results being known. No RDBMS (that I know of) offers any means of determining how many results to a query have been found prior to the query completing.

I can't speak factually for how expensive such a feature would be in Oracle because I have never seen the source code. From the outside in, however, I think it would be rather costly and could double (if not more) the length of time a query took to complete. It would mean updating an atomic counter after each result, which isn't cheap when you're talking millions of possible rows.

Answer (score 1):

So I am putting up my comments into this answer-
In terms of Oracle.

Oracle maintains its own buffer cache inside the system global area (SGA) for each instance. The hit ratio on the buffer cache depends on the sizing and reaches 90% most of the time, which means 9 out of 10 hits will be satisfied without reaching the disk.

Considering the above, even if there is a "way" (so to speak) to access the buffer chache for a query you run, the results would highly depend on the cache sizing factor. If a buffer cache is too small, the cache hit ratio will be small and more physical disk I/O will result, which will render the buffer cache un-reliable in terms of temp-data content. If a buffer cache is too big, then parts of the buffer cache will be under-utilized and memory resources will be wasted, which in terms would render too much un-necessary processing trying to access the buffer cache while in order to peek in it for the data you want.

Also depending on your cache sizing and SGA memory it would be upto the ODBC driver / optimizer to determine when and how much to use what (cache buffering or Direct Disk I/O).

In terms of trying to access the "buffer cache" to find "the row" you are looking for, there might be a way (or in near future) to do it, but there would be no way to know if what  you are looking for ("The row") is there or not after all.

Also, full table scans of large tables usually result in physical disk reads and a lower buffer cache hit ratio.You can get an idea of full table scan activity at the data file level by querying `v$filestat` and joining to `SYS.dba_data_files`. Following is a query you can use and sample results:

```
 SELECT   A.file_name, B.phyrds, B.phyblkrd
 FROM     SYS.dba_data_files A, v$filestat B
 WHERE    B.file# = A.file_id
 ORDER BY A.file_id;
```

Since this whole ordeal is highly based on multiple parameters and statistics, the results of what you are looking for may remain a probability driven off of those facotrs.

Comment: any row, even just one row which satisfies the query's criteria would be desirable to peek at, while the query continues its search.. this is what I'd be looking for, if such data is stored in the fetch buffer or wherever the current list (result set) is stored and normally released for viewing when the query completes!.. I don't exactly know the internal workings of how servers handle this, nor do I know what goes on in this area when a full table scan or sorting, due to an ORDER BY clause is performed.

Comment: but there is no way to know if what you are looking for is there at all! the Buffer Cache is mostly the engines own scratch pad accessible to all concurrent transactions and processes. It would be like finding "needle in a haystack" at times, and the needle may not even be there.

Comment: I would think that wherever the engine chooses to temporarily store a specific query's result set should be accessible in one particular place, and not mixed up with other stuff?

Comment: Thats more and more dynamic an I would expect it to be more flexible in newer versions of Oracle. The "wherever the engine chooses" is based on a lot of parameters both at a Hardware level and system level of the server/machine, and since different servers may have different configs, no. of CPUs, Memory, Disk capacity etc., it would be wise for the optimizer to determine the "what to choose" on the fly. What you said sounds more like a "Buffer cache" for "Buffer cache and Disk IO", and hence all the rules apply to that buffer cache as well!