# When does a SELECT query begin to return rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

Suppose the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table;
```

Will the DBMS give me the first row as soon as it fetched it or will it first fetch all the rows (save them in some kind of buffer) and then give me all the rows at once?

If my question was not clear. Suppose that the amount of rows in the `table` is such that the DBMS will take exactly 60 minutes to fetch all the rows. Will the DBMS return the rows progressively through the 60 minutes, or will I have to wait 60 minutes before receiving any data?

Comment: Hmmm... interesting. What did your testing suggest?

Comment: @AndrewMorton My testing suggests that it uses some kind of cache. Also, I believe it would be easier to handle transactions with the cache approach. But, I did test only with `psql` so far, so I dont know if the behavior is due to `psql` or due to the dbms.

Comment: psql has same behave like typical simple application. It is based over libpq, so libpq collect all data in memory on client side, and when query is complete, then returns control to client. You can redefine it to using a cursors by setting FETCH_COUNT to 1000 (returns to client after fetching 1000 rows) - \set FETCH_COUNT 1000

Comment: It sure would be nice to have an option other than the FIRST ROWS directive to immediately preview partial results while the query continues searching. Especially when users know the query may only return few results from a large table! See my related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563358/begin-viewing-query-results-before-query-ends).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, the server will indeed return rows to the client as soon as they are available if the query execution plan permits it.  This is the case in your simple example.  In other cases, if you might have a sort at the end, for example, and will have to wait for that to finish.

But if you use the standard libpq interface, the client library will build up the entire result in memory before it returns it to the client program.  To get the results row by row, you need to use the [single-row mode](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-single-row-mode.html) in libpq.  If you use other interfaces or other languages, results might vary.

Comment: Do you know of any solution prior to 9.2?

Comment: Use a server-side cursor.

Answer (score 3):

There is no hard rule here.  But in practice, the database engine should prefer to return rows as soon as they are available.  The efficiency advantage is large and obvious.

Note that this is not possible for all queries.  A very common example is an `order by` clause that has no supporting index.  In order to sort, the database has to create a server-side copy of the table that is sorted.  This means it can't start returning rows until the sort operation is completed.

Answer (score 1):

Most, if not all, SQL-based servers will not allow you to view any rows until the query completes searching. Some servers provide a FIRST ROWS directive (a hint) for the server to provide the first set of rows sooner. See my related [SO question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563358/begin-viewing-query-results-before-query-ends) for more info on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

For example, the Oracle Database will optimize for throughput by default and try to return all the rows, or you can instruct the optimizer to return the first *n* rows with the `/*+ FIRST_ROWS(n) */ [optimizer hint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16638/hintsref.htm#CHDFIAJD).

As for PostgresSQL, it doesn't have optmizer hints (see [these](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/database-soup/why-postgresql-doesnt-have-query-hints-44121) [two](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo#Features_We_Do_Not_Want) links). I can assume it will try to optimize for throughput by default.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't use a hints for this purpose, but when you use a cursor, then query is optimized for fast first 10% rows (default value of cursor_tuple_fraction).